# Why the Button have this padding?

Tags: html, css, button

You can see the code of the page [here](http://www.gabbatracklistworld.com/problems.php).

I don't know why there is that padding with yellow background around the Button. I've also tried to put the same code on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKuAp/), but seems that there isn't that padding.

Which attribute I miss?

Comment: Fiddle uses a stylesheet that normalizes everything: http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css

Comment: @pole : reply with yout answer, you'll get the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div element has a default of 5px padding if I remember correctly.

Try adding an id tag,

```
<div id="box">
```

And use this css:

```
#box {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your div that wraps the button has an inline style that sets the background yellow:

```
 <div class="categoryName4" style="background-color:#FFFF00;">
```

Comment: It also has a set width, which is why there's a gap between the div and the button.

Comment: Isn't the yellow just there so we can see the "extra padding"?

Comment: I got the impression from the way the question was worded that the yellow was also mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

The containing `<div>` has fixed width - get rid of that and you won't have that "padding".